# Why did I get this behaviour?

Tags: parallel-processing, chapel

I was going through the specification of Chapel and was reading on Task Level Parallelism, in particular the synchronization variables (sync and single) and the logical state of them and how they go about. I came across this example given in the specification on this [Link](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/language/spec/task-parallelism-and-synchronization.html)

```
var count$: sync int=0;
cobegin{
    count$+=1
    count$+=1
    count$+=1
}
```

On [***running*** the above code](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIITm/NK9ExUqhuDIvWSEzr8TWwJorOT8pNT0zr5pLAQggCrRtDfHyav//BwA), I get an error but the specification does not talk about it and expects the program to run properly. Why do I get this behaviour?

Comment: If in doubts, test the code in an available online-IDE, there the syntax error gets *(sometimes somewhat cryptic, I admit, yet helpful)* advice from where the compilation failed, so rapid prototyping and/or fast mock-up testing is indeed very productive there - **`syntax error: near 'count$'`** *( for more details kindly see the link inlined into your question and may re-run the code after syntax corrections or changes )* ... Wow, 've seen Brad's answer below just after refresh of this post / update ( now it seems a bit redundant, yet left, well for a complete picture )

Answer (score 3):

In the specification, the count$ += 1 lines each have a semicolon at the end:

```
var count$: sync int = 0;
cobegin {
  count$ += 1;
  count$ += 1;
  count$ += 1;
}
```

which works for me.

Without the semicolons, the syntax error is expected.

However, the `internal error: assertion error [AST/build.cpp:2374]` (or `internal error: AST-BUI-2374 ...` is unexpected.  As its discoverer, would you like to open an issue in the issue tracker: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues
?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the internal error... I'd completely overlooked that.

Comment: I put together a fix for it here:  https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/16815

Answer (score 3):

Chapel is a language that uses semicolons to terminate statements in order to avoid ambiguities.  It looks to me like you dropped the semicolons from the three statements within the `cobegin` when transcribing the example from the language specification and that it should work once they are restored ([TIO](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIITm/NK9ExUqhuDIvWSEzr8TWwJorOT8pNT0zr5pLAQggCrRtDa0JcGu5yosyS1Jz8jQggnpFqYkpbq4amprW//8DAA)):

```
var count$: sync int=0;
cobegin{
    count$+=1;
    count$+=1;
    count$+=1;
}
writeln(count$.readFE());
```

Note that most of the examples in the language specification are available within the Chapel release in the `$CHPL_HOME/examples/spec/` directory, organized by chapter so that they need not be re-typed or cut-and-pasted.  For example, that example (whose name is indicated as `syncCounter.chpl`) can be found in `$CHPL_HOME/examples/spec/Task_Parallelism_and_Synchronization/syncCounter.chpl`.

If you're working from the development branch on GitHub rather than an official release, they can be found in `$CHPL_HOME/test/release/examples/spec` after you have executed a `make spectests` command from the `$CHPL_HOME` directory.